# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding()

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, wamp

I received the following error trying to acces http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc:177 Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc(282): _encode('The %s extensio...') #1 C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc(289): _gettext('The %s extensio...') #2 C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\core.lib.php(306): __('The %s extensio...') #3 C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\core.lib.php(961): PMA_warnMissingExtension('mbstring', true) #4 C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\common.inc.php(102): PMA_checkExtensions() #5 C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\index.php(13): require_once('C:\\Apache24\\htd...') #6 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177
```

After reviewing similar topics here, I did the following:

1. Checked (using info.php) the path of my php.ini file : 
   Loaded Configuration File    C:\PHP\php.ini
2. Modified and uncommented the following lines in php.ini:

   - extension_dir = "c:\PHP\ext" (also tried "c:/PHP/ext")
   - extension=php_gd2.dll
   - extension=php_mbstring.dll
   - extension=php_exif.dll
   - extension=php_mysqli.dll
3. Tried both 32bits and 64bits dlls
4. Made sure that all the dll were in the c:/PHP/ext file and righ-clicked>properties>unblock each of them.
5. Restarted httpd.exe many time, rebooted the server too.

Here is the content of my httpd.conf Apache config file :

Here is the content of my httpd.conf :

```
LoadModule php7_module C:/PHP/php7apache2_4.dll

<IfModule php7_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
    PHPIniDir "C:/PHP"
</IfModule>
```

I keep receiving the same message with no clue how to solve it.

I am running windows 10, with Apache 2.4-64bits, PHP7-64bits and MysqlServer5.7. Apache is running fine, PHP too (no worries accessing info.php)

Thanks.

Comment: It is best to use the unix forward slash as windows versions of PHP etc will automatically do any conversion, but using `/` in a double quoted string removes the possibility of it getting confused with the escape character

Comment: Run `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and check you are editing the correct `php.ini` file

Comment: @RiggsFolly, that's what I meant in my 1st point. But thanks.
so "c:/PHP/ext" should be the best ?

Comment: Can you find php_mbstring.dll under "c:\PHP\ext"?

Comment: Yes, both php_mbstring.dll and php_mysqli.dll are under c:/PHP/ext/

Comment: Good, make sure they are not set to read-only

Comment: I forgot to mention that, but you're right, I "unblocked" every single of them.

Comment: Just in case. Are sure that you saved changes in php.ini? Do you have other lines with "extension_dir" in php.ini?

Comment: Yes, changes are saved, and no other occurences of "extension_dir". thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard that Apache2.4 has some problems with PHPINIDir. So try to add `PHPIniDir "C:\PHP"` in http.conf

Comment: You mean httpd.conf?

I updated my question with the content of my httpd.conf file

Comment: Good. I do not have more ideas for now

Comment: All right. Thanks though. Also I was thinking that I never linked my MySql database to phpMyAdmin in any ways (never specified any path or so) could the problem come from that?

Comment: I don't think so. If you had never used it before, you may have problems with connection to MySql, but your current problem is different